# Calculate base effect based on month to month changes in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a sample dataframe `df` which is CPI data having `date` and `MoM` columns, I need to calculate `base_effect` and `new_price_effect` based on them:

```
       date    MoM  base_effect  new_price_effect
0   2019-01  1.010          NaN               NaN
1   2019-02  1.010          NaN               NaN
2   2019-03  1.010          NaN               NaN
3   2019-04  1.010          NaN               NaN
4   2019-05  1.010          NaN               NaN
5   2019-06  1.010          NaN               NaN
6   2019-07  1.010          NaN               NaN
7   2019-08  1.010          NaN               NaN
8   2019-09  1.010          NaN               NaN
9   2019-10  1.010          NaN               NaN
10  2019-11  1.010          NaN               NaN
11  2019-12  1.010          NaN               NaN
12  2020-01  1.015     1.115668          1.015000
13  2020-02  1.015     1.104622          1.030225
14  2020-03  1.015     1.093685          1.045678
15  2020-04  1.015     1.082857          1.061364
16  2020-05  1.015     1.072135          1.077284
17  2020-06  1.015     1.061520          1.093443
18  2020-07  1.015     1.051010          1.109845
19  2020-08  1.015     1.040604          1.126493
20  2020-09  1.015     1.030301          1.143390
21  2020-10  1.015     1.020100          1.160541
22  2020-11  1.015     1.010000          1.177949
23  2020-12  1.015     1.000000          1.195618
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': '2019-01', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-02', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-03', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-04', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-05', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-06', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-07', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-08', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-09', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-10', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-11', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2019-12', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': np.NaN, 'new_price_effect': np.NaN},
 {'date': '2020-01',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.115668347,
  'new_price_effect': 1.015},
 {'date': '2020-02',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.104622125,
  'new_price_effect': 1.030225},
 {'date': '2020-03',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.093685273,
  'new_price_effect': 1.045678375},
 {'date': '2020-04',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.082856706,
  'new_price_effect': 1.061363551},
 {'date': '2020-05',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.072135352,
  'new_price_effect': 1.077284004},
 {'date': '2020-06',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.061520151,
  'new_price_effect': 1.093443264},
 {'date': '2020-07',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.05101005,
  'new_price_effect': 1.109844913},
 {'date': '2020-08',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.04060401,
  'new_price_effect': 1.126492587},
 {'date': '2020-09',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.030301,
  'new_price_effect': 1.143389975},
 {'date': '2020-10',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.0201,
  'new_price_effect': 1.160540825},
 {'date': '2020-11',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.01,
  'new_price_effect': 1.177948937},
 {'date': '2020-12',
  'MoM': 1.015,
  'base_effect': 1.0,
  'new_price_effect': 1.195618171}])
```

The calculation of `base_effect` is based on the following formula:

[image]

ie: to calculate base effect of `2020-06`, we use `MoM(2019-07) * MoM(2019-08) * MoM(2019-09) * MoM(2019-10) * MoM(2019-11) * MoM(2019-12) = 1.061520`, for `2020-09`, `MoM(2019-10) * MoM(2019-11) * MoM(2019-12) = 1.030301`

The `new_price_effect` is based on:

[image]

ie: to calculate new price effect of `2020-04`, we use `MoM(2020-01) * MoM(2020-02) * MoM(2020-03) * MoM(2020-04) = 1.061364`; for `2020-06`, `MoM(2020-01) * MoM(2020-02) * MoM(2020-03) * MoM(2020-04) * MoM(2020-05) * MoM(2020-06) = 1.093443`, etc.

We can see for `base_effect`, the `MoM` of `December` of previous year is fixed, while for `new_price_effect`, the `MoM` of `January` of current year is fixed. And **the base effect of for each `December` is always `1.00`**.

How could I calculate them with Pandas? Thanks.

**Updated data** which returns `NaN`s for `base_effect` and `new_price_effect`:

```
data = [{'date': '2020-1-31', 'MoM': 1.014},
 {'date': '2020-2-29', 'MoM': 1.008},
 {'date': '2020-3-31', 'MoM': 0.988},
 {'date': '2020-4-30', 'MoM': 0.991},
 {'date': '2020-5-31', 'MoM': 0.992},
 {'date': '2020-6-30', 'MoM': 0.999339},
 {'date': '2020-7-31', 'MoM': 1.006159},
 {'date': '2020-8-31', 'MoM': 1.00401},
 {'date': '2020-9-30', 'MoM': 1.002325},
 {'date': '2020-10-31', 'MoM': 0.997},
 {'date': '2020-11-30', 'MoM': 0.9940000000000001},
 {'date': '2020-12-31', 'MoM': 1.0070000000000001},
 {'date': '2021-1-31', 'MoM': 1.01},
 {'date': '2021-2-28', 'MoM': 1.006},
 {'date': '2021-3-31', 'MoM': 0.995},
 {'date': '2021-4-30', 'MoM': 0.997},
 {'date': '2021-5-31', 'MoM': 0.998},
 {'date': '2021-6-30', 'MoM': 0.996},
 {'date': '2021-7-31', 'MoM': 1.003},
 {'date': '2021-8-31', 'MoM': 1.001}]
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
from datetime import datetime

data = [{'date': '2019-01', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-02', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-03', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-04', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-05', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-06', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-07', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-08', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-09', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-10', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-11', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2019-12', 'MoM': 1.01, 'base_effect': nan, 'new_price_effect': nan},
        {'date': '2020-01',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.115668347,
         'new_price_effect': 1.015},
        {'date': '2020-02',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.104622125,
         'new_price_effect': 1.030225},
        {'date': '2020-03',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.093685273,
         'new_price_effect': 1.045678375},
        {'date': '2020-04',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.082856706,
         'new_price_effect': 1.061363551},
        {'date': '2020-05',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.072135352,
         'new_price_effect': 1.077284004},
        {'date': '2020-06',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.061520151,
         'new_price_effect': 1.093443264},
        {'date': '2020-07',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.05101005,
         'new_price_effect': 1.109844913},
        {'date': '2020-08',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.04060401,
         'new_price_effect': 1.126492587},
        {'date': '2020-09',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.030301,
         'new_price_effect': 1.143389975},
        {'date': '2020-10',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.0201,
         'new_price_effect': 1.160540825},
        {'date': '2020-11',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.01,
         'new_price_effect': 1.177948937},
        {'date': '2020-12',
         'MoM': 1.015,
         'base_effect': 1.0,
         'new_price_effect': 1.195618171}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df)


def base_effect(x):
    required_interval = pd.date_range(x['date'] - relativedelta(months=11), freq='MS',
                                      periods=12 - x['date'].month)
    df_sub = df[df.date.isin(required_interval)]
    return df_sub['MoM'].product(min_count=1)


def new_price_effect(x):
    required_interval = pd.date_range(datetime(x['date'].year, 1, 1), freq='MS', periods=x['date'].month)
    df_sub = df[df.date.isin(required_interval)]
    return df_sub['MoM'].product(min_count=1)

df['base_effect'] = df.apply(base_effect, axis=1)
df['new_price_effect'] = df.apply(new_price_effect, axis=1)
print(df)
```

If you want to use it with other columns try:

```
def base_effect(x,col_name):
    required_interval = pd.date_range(x['date'] - relativedelta(months=11), freq='MS',
                                      periods=12 - x['date'].month)
    df_sub = df[df.date.isin(required_interval)]
    return df_sub[col_name].product(min_count=1)


def new_price_effect(x, col_name):
    required_interval = pd.date_range(datetime(x['date'].year, 1, 1), freq='MS', periods=x['date'].month)
    df_sub = df[df.date.isin(required_interval)]
    return df_sub[col_name].product(min_count=1)

df['base_effect'] = df.apply(base_effect, col_name='MoM', axis=1)
df['new_price_effect'] = df.apply(new_price_effect, col_name='MoM', axis=1)
print(df)
```

As the updated data have end dates for months, `isin` wont work with `MS` frequency. You can update your functions as follows:

```
def base_effect(x,col_name):
    required_interval = list(pd.date_range(x['date'] - relativedelta(months=11), freq='MS',
                                      periods=12 - x['date'].month))
    if required_interval:
        df_sub = df[(df.date>=required_interval[0]) & (df.date<=required_interval[-1])]

        return df_sub[col_name].product(min_count=1)
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Comment: I tested your code, it raises an error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Could u pls re-test and post the result?

Comment: Can you specify the line please, which caused the error. Worked fine for me.

Comment: The error I got from `required_interval = pd.date_range(datetime(x['date'].year, 1, 1), freq='MS', periods=x['date'].month)`. No problem for `df.apply(base_effect, axis=1)`.

Comment: Run the edited code, its working fine for the data you provided in the question

Comment: Sorry, one more question, if I have multiple columns ie., `MoM1`, `MoM2`, ..., etc, how could I modify your code to calculate `base_effect` and `new_price_effect` for each?

Comment: I didn't get you, how do you want to use those additional columns?

Comment: I mean besides `MoM`, I have other columns similar to it need to calculate `base_effect` and `new_price_effect` as well.

Comment: Check the edited answer, just replace MoM with your column of choice. is this what u want?

Comment: Sorry, I get another error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'` for `pd.date_range(datetime(x['date'].year, 1, 1), freq='MS', periods=x['date'].month)`, the data type of `date` column is `dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: I found it works fine when I use `pd.read_clipboard()`, but as I read excel directly, it raises error above.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what exactly is going wrong at your end, its working fine for me. However I didn't try it by reading from excel instead I used the df u provided in the question

Comment: Could u pls test with new data I added in the end of this post?

Answer (score 0):

For the updated data, I need to floor a date to the first date of that month:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
from datetime import datetime

data = [{'date': '2020-1-31', 'MoM': 1.014},
 {'date': '2020-2-29', 'MoM': 1.008},
 {'date': '2020-3-31', 'MoM': 0.988},
 {'date': '2020-4-30', 'MoM': 0.991},
 {'date': '2020-5-31', 'MoM': 0.992},
 {'date': '2020-6-30', 'MoM': 0.999339},
 {'date': '2020-7-31', 'MoM': 1.006159},
 {'date': '2020-8-31', 'MoM': 1.00401},
 {'date': '2020-9-30', 'MoM': 1.002325},
 {'date': '2020-10-31', 'MoM': 0.997},
 {'date': '2020-11-30', 'MoM': 0.9940000000000001},
 {'date': '2020-12-31', 'MoM': 1.0070000000000001},
 {'date': '2021-1-31', 'MoM': 1.01},
 {'date': '2021-2-28', 'MoM': 1.006},
 {'date': '2021-3-31', 'MoM': 0.995},
 {'date': '2021-4-30', 'MoM': 0.997},
 {'date': '2021-5-31', 'MoM': 0.998},
 {'date': '2021-6-30', 'MoM': 0.996},
 {'date': '2021-7-31', 'MoM': 1.003},
 {'date': '2021-8-31', 'MoM': 1.001}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - MonthBegin(1)


def base_effect(x):
    required_interval = pd.date_range(x['date'] - relativedelta(months=11), freq='MS',
                                      periods=12 - x['date'].month)
    df_sub = df[df.date.isin(required_interval)]
    return df_sub['MoM'].product(min_count=1)


def new_price_effect(x):
    required_interval = pd.date_range(datetime(x['date'].year, 1, 1), freq='MS', periods=x['date'].month)
    df_sub = df[df.date.isin(required_interval)]
    return df_sub['MoM'].product(min_count=1)

df['base_effect'] = df.apply(base_effect, axis=1)
df['new_price_effect'] = df.apply(new_price_effect, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Out:

```
         date       MoM  base_effect  new_price_effect
0  2020-01-01  1.014000          NaN          1.014000
1  2020-02-01  1.008000          NaN          1.022112
2  2020-03-01  0.988000          NaN          1.009847
3  2020-04-01  0.991000          NaN          1.000758
4  2020-05-01  0.992000          NaN          0.992752
5  2020-06-01  0.999339          NaN          0.992096
6  2020-07-01  1.006159          NaN          0.998206
7  2020-08-01  1.004010          NaN          1.002209
8  2020-09-01  1.002325          NaN          1.004539
9  2020-10-01  0.997000          NaN          1.001525
10 2020-11-01  0.994000          NaN          0.995516
11 2020-12-01  1.007000          NaN          1.002485
12 2021-01-01  1.010000     0.988644          1.010000
13 2021-02-01  1.006000     0.980797          1.016060
14 2021-03-01  0.995000     0.992710          1.010980
15 2021-04-01  0.997000     1.001726          1.007947
16 2021-05-01  0.998000     1.009804          1.005931
17 2021-06-01  0.996000     1.010472          1.001907
18 2021-07-01  1.003000     1.004286          1.004913
19 2021-08-01  1.001000     1.000275          1.005918
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the code of @Muhammad Hassan, I think the most important thing is to get `base_effect_date_interval` and `new_price_effect_date_interval`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
from datetime import datetime

date = pd.to_datetime('2021-06-30')
base_effect_date_interval = pd.date_range(date - relativedelta(months=11), freq='MS',
                                  periods=12 - date.month) - pd.offsets.Day(1)


new_price_effect_date_interval = pd.date_range(datetime(date.year, 1, 1), freq='MS', periods=date.month) + MonthEnd(0)
base_effect_date_interval
new_price_effect_date_interval
```

Out:

```
base_effect_date_interval
Out[48]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-07-31', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31',
               '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

new_price_effect_date_interval
Out[49]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30',
               '2021-05-31', '2021-06-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```