# Calculate base effect based on month to month changes in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's say we have a sample dataframe `df` which is a fake CPI data having `date` and `MoM` columns, I need to calculate `base_effect` and `new_price_effect` based on them:

```
       date    MoM  base_effect  new_price_effect
0   2019-01  1.010          NA               NA
1   2019-02  1.010          NA               NA
2   2019-03  1.010          NA               NA
3   2019-04  1.010          NA               NA
4   2019-05  1.010          NA               NA
5   2019-06  1.010          NA               NA
6   2019-07  1.010          NA               NA
7   2019-08  1.010          NA               NA
8   2019-09  1.010          NA               NA
9   2019-10  1.010          NA               NA
10  2019-11  1.010          NA               NA
11  2019-12  1.010          NA               NA
12  2020-01  1.015     1.115668          1.015000
13  2020-02  1.015     1.104622          1.030225
14  2020-03  1.015     1.093685          1.045678
15  2020-04  1.015     1.082857          1.061364
16  2020-05  1.015     1.072135          1.077284
17  2020-06  1.015     1.061520          1.093443
18  2020-07  1.015     1.051010          1.109845
19  2020-08  1.015     1.040604          1.126493
20  2020-09  1.015     1.030301          1.143390
21  2020-10  1.015     1.020100          1.160541
22  2020-11  1.015     1.010000          1.177949
23  2020-12  1.015     1.000000          1.195618
```

Or:

```
structure(list(date = c("2019-1-1", "2019-2-1", "2019-3-1", "2019-4-1", 
"2019-5-1", "2019-6-1", "2019-7-1", "2019-8-1", "2019-9-1", "2019-10-1", 
"2019-11-1", "2019-12-1", "2020-1-1", "2020-2-1", "2020-3-1", 
"2020-4-1", "2020-5-1", "2020-6-1", "2020-7-1", "2020-8-1", "2020-9-1", 
"2020-10-1", "2020-11-1", "2020-12-1"), MoM = c(1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 
1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.015, 
1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 1.015, 
1.015, 1.015)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

The calculation of `base_effect` is based on the following formula:

[image]

ie: to calculate base effect of `2020-06`, we use `MoM(2019-07) * MoM(2019-08) * MoM(2019-09) * MoM(2019-10) * MoM(2019-11) * MoM(2019-12) = 1.061520`, for `2020-09`, `MoM(2019-10) * MoM(2019-11) * MoM(2019-12) = 1.030301`

The `new_price_effect` is based on:

[image]

ie: to calculate new price effect of `2020-04`, we use `MoM(2020-01) * MoM(2020-02) * MoM(2020-03) * MoM(2020-04) = 1.061364`; for `2020-06`, `MoM(2020-01) * MoM(2020-02) * MoM(2020-03) * MoM(2020-04) * MoM(2020-05) * MoM(2020-06) = 1.093443`, etc.

We can see for `base_effect`, the `MoM` of `December` of previous year is fixed, while for `new_price_effect`, the `MoM` of `January` of current year is fixed. And `the base effect of for each December is always 1.00.`

How could I calculate them with R? Thanks.

Reference:

[Calculate base effect based on month to month changes in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503481/calculate-base-effect-based-on-month-to-month-changes-in-pandas)

Comment: for 2020-09, would't 1.015 ^ 3 = 1.0456 not 1.030301? Are you sure MoM changes from 1.01 in 2020?

Comment: `base_effect` is calculated based on the `MoM`s of previous year, so for its value for `2020-09` is `MoM(2019-10) * MoM(2019-11) * MoM(2019-12) = 1.030301`, while `new_price_effect` is calculated by the `MoM`s of the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives the desired result. It is based on `cumprod(MoM)` grouped by year, with a few additional tricks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date), year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% 
  arrange(year,month)

warning("This only works if df is complete (no missing month). If not, first tidyr::complete()")
df = df %>% mutate(MoM_prev_year=lag(MoM, 12))

df = df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(
    new_price_effect = cumprod(MoM), 
    base_effect = rev(cumprod(rev(MoM_prev_year)))/MoM_prev_year
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```